# A string that shows the generated number

Tags: javascript

I want to add a string that shows the current amount of pictures generated from the code, like "number of pictures:"

```
<h1 id="number-of-p">Antall bilder:</h1>
<input id="add-img-btn" type="button" value="Legg til bilde" />
<div id="output-div"></div>

<script>
  var addImgBtn = document.getElementById("add-img-btn");
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output-div");
  var addNumberOfP = document.getElementById("number-of-p");

  function addRandomNumber() {
    const rnd = (addNumberOfP = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    let html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= rnd; i++) {}
    numberOfP.innerHTML = html.join("");
  }

  function addRandomImg() {
    const rnd = (addImgBtn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    let html = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= rnd; i++) {
      html.push('<img src="img/mann.jpg"/>');
    }
    outputDiv.innerHTML = html.join("");
  }

  addImgBtn.onclick = addRandomImg;
  addNumberOfP.onclick = addRandomNumber;
</script>
```

Comment: The `addRandomNumber` function does nothing; it has an empty loop, and `html` is an empty array. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this will work!

```js
var addImgBtn = document.getElementById("add-img-btn");
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output-div");
var addNumberOfP = document.getElementById("number-of-p");

function addRandomImg() {
  const rnd = (addImgBtn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
  let html = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= rnd; i++) {
    html.push('<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg"/>');
  }
  outputDiv.innerHTML = html.join("");
  addNumberOfP.innerHTML = `Antall bilder: ${(rnd + 1)}`;
}

addImgBtn.onclick = addRandomImg;
```

```html
<h1 id="number-of-p">Antall bilder:</h1>
<input id="add-img-btn" type="button" value="Legg til bilde" />
<div id="output-div"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesnt seem to work :O

Comment: @rubenduben I've made it into a code snippet, it works when you run it there

Comment: It should be `i < rnd` not `i <= rnd` if you expect `rnd` to be the number of images displayed (currently it's off by one).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Fixed, I got the impression the asker was just struggling to get the text in the H1 eg innerHTML wasn't working for them.